# Problems configuring TypeScript in Laravel, Vuejs and Inertia

Tags: php, typescript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I use the tech stack Laravel, Vue and Inertia. Now I wanted to convert everything to TypeScript and I ran into a problem that I can't fix. I took this video to help me:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDcsrGGvCHI

I implemented everything as in the video. But now when I start npm run dev I get the following message in Chrome's dev tool: to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
I have tried to solve the problem on my own, but I can't get any further. The message says that there is a server problem, so some setting must not fit.Can someone help me please? Here would be my configs

resources/js/app.ts

```
import "../css/app.css";
import { createApp, h, type DefineComponent } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers'

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: async (name: string) => {
        let page = await resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob<DefineComponent>('./Pages/**/*.vue'))
        return page
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el)
    },
})
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   
    "target": "es2016",                                  
    "jsx": "preserve",                                
    "module": "commonjs",                               
    "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./resources/js/*"]
    },                                                            
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                       
    "allowJs": true,                                  
    "isolatedModules": true,                                    
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,           
    "strict": true,                                             
    "skipLibCheck": true                                
  }
}
```

resources/views/app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    @vite('resources/js/app.ts')
    @inertiaHead
</head>
<body>
@inertia
</body>
</html>
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.ts'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

example of my Parent Component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, reactive, ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import WeatherDisplay  from './WeatherDisplay';
import { Refs, WeatherData } from '../interfaces/interfaces'
import { useDark, useToggle } from '@vueuse/core';
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const isDark = useDark();
const toggleDark = useToggle(isDark);

// Define the props for the component
const props = defineProps<{
    data: Object,
}>();

// This object contains all required refs
const allRefs = ref<Refs>({
    searchWeather: '',
    errorMessage: null,
});

// Creates a reactive array that is updated with weatherData
const weatherData = reactive<WeatherData[]>([]);

// Function to load data from local storage
function loadDataFromLocalStorage(): WeatherData[] {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('weatherData');
    return data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];
}

// Function to set data to local storage
function setDataToLocalStorage(data: WeatherData[]) {
    weatherData.push(props.data);
    localStorage.setItem('weatherData', JSON.stringify(data));
}

// Delete weather data from array and local storage
function deleteWeatherData(index: number) {
    weatherData.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('weatherData', JSON.stringify(weatherData));
}

// Load the data from local storage on mounted
onMounted(() => {
    const savedData = loadDataFromLocalStorage();
    if (savedData.length > 0) {
        weatherData.splice(0, weatherData.length, ...savedData);
    }

    if (props.data && !props.data.error) {
        setDataToLocalStorage(weatherData);
    } else if (props.data && props.data.error) {
        allRefs.value.errorMessage = props.data.error.message;
        console.log(allRefs.value.errorMessage);
    }
});

// Define a method to send the GET request to the backend
async function submit() {
    try {
        await router.get('/weather',  { searchWeather: allRefs.value.searchWeather });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <main :class="{ 'dark-mode': isDark }">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-96">
            <div
                class="mb-4 text-center text-4xl font-bold dark:text-[#7371FF]"
            >
                SecureClouds
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-row justify-end mb-4">
                <div class="mr-4 flex items-center">
                    <span class="text-xl dark:text-[#7371FF]">
                        {{ isDark ? 'Dark' : 'Light' }} Mode
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button
                        @click="toggleDark()"
                        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded dark:bg-[#22F1BF] dark:text-black"
                    >
                        Switch
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="block w-2/3 rounded-lg">
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                    <div class="w-2/3 p-4">
                        <div
                            v-if="allRefs.errorMessage"
                            class="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative"
                            role="alert"
                        >
                            <strong class="font-bold">{{
                                allRefs.errorMessage
                            }}</strong>
                        </div>

                        <form @submit.prevent="submit" class="w-full">
                            <div
                                class="relative mb-4 flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch"
                            >
                                <input
                                    type="search"
                                    class="relative bg-[#F9F3EE] m-0 -mr-px block flex-auto border border-neutral-300 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-transparent bg-clip-padding px-6 py-4 text-lg font-normal text-neutral-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-in-out focus:border-primary-600 focus:text-neutral-700 focus:shadow-te-primary focus:outline-none dark:border-[#22F1BF] dark:text-[#22F1BF] dark:placeholder:text-[#22F1BF]"
                                    placeholder="Suchen..."
                                    name="searchWeather"
                                    aria-label="Search"
                                    aria-describedby="button-addon3"
                                    v-model="allRefs.searchWeather"
                                />
                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    class="bg-[#F9F3EE] hover:bg-slate-200 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-6 border border-neutral-300 rounded-lg shadow ml-4 dark:bg-[#22F1BF] dark:border-[#22F1BF] dark:text-black"
                                >
                                    Suchen
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            <WeatherDisplay
                v-for="(data, index) in weatherData"
                :key="index"
                :data="data"
                @delete="deleteWeatherData(index)"
            >
            </WeatherDisplay>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>

<style>
main {
    background-color: #b2c8df;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
.dark-mode {
    background: #0d1117;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Laravel Breeze with Inertia and Typescript and then check how they have configured it.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia

Create new Laravel Project

Install Breeze:

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

Setup Breeze with Inertia and Typescript:

```
php artisan breeze:install vue
```

And say 'yes' on the question about TypeScript.

Here is an blog article about it:
https://larainfo.com/blogs/install-laravel-10-inertia-vue-3-with-typescript

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I started a new project and raised it as in the blog articel. now I noticed that as soon as I use lang="ts" in the script tag, I always get that as an error: node[17077]: ../src/module_wrap.cc:599:v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Promise> node::loader::ImportModuleDynamically(v8::Local<v8::Context>
, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::FixedArray>): Assertion `(it) != (env->id_to_
function_map.end())' failed.
 1: 0xbf9680 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xbf96fe  [node]
 3: 0xbaf577  [node]
 4: 0xf5966f

Comment: Looks like that there is a bug in node 19.8.0 right now. Maybe that is your problem as well?
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47096
Upgrade to 19.8.1 or downgrade 19.7.0  may fix it.
But it's just a guess. I did not seen such a error in my projects so far.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

here is how you fix it.

app.ts

make sure you import DefineComponent

```
import "./bootstrap";
import "../css/app.css"; 
import { createApp, h, DefineComponent } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers"; 
import { translations } from "@/Mixins/translations";

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || "Laravel";
 

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) =>
        resolvePageComponent(
            `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
            import.meta.glob<DefineComponent>("./Pages/**/*.vue")
        ),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin) 
            .mount(el);
    } 
});
```

tsconfig.json change or add

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    ...
    },
    "include": ["resources/js/**/*.ts", "resources/js/**/*.d.ts", "resources/js/**/*.vue"]
}
```

install types for your package dependencies,
ie
npm i -D typescript vue-tsc

globally define your props type
example index.d.ts

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    email_verified_at: string;
}

export type PageProps<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> = T & {
    auth: {
        user: User;
    };
};
```

global.d.ts

```
import { PageProps as InertiaPageProps } from '@inertiajs/core';
import { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { PageProps as AppPageProps } from './';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        axios: AxiosInstance;
    }
 
}

declare module 'vue' {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        
    }
}

declare module '@inertiajs/core' {
    interface PageProps extends InertiaPageProps, AppPageProps {}
}
```

you good to go